# render :inline => "<%= yield %>" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I'm upgrading from Rails 2.3.8 to 3.0.3 and notice that my code for nested layouts isn't working.

In my main Application layout I have the line

<%= controller.sub_layout %>

which then looks to the controller, who has:

```
def sub_layout
    render :inline => "<%= yield %>"
    # or otherwise some partial for the sub-layout
end
```

The problem is, this doesn't get rendered!  If I put a direct <%= yield %> statement in the layout, it does work.  So the question is, what's happening here, and how do I fix it?

This worked beautifully in Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you all have some more of a background on this, the whole sub-layout approach was based on this blog post: [Sorta Nested Layouts](http://www.cs8.my/nested-layouts-in-rails/) (The solution is given in the comments section.)

Instead of making a controller method sub_layout, any controller that uses a sublayout needs to define a before_filter method that sets a variable:

```
def inner_layout
  @inner_layout = 'layouts/sublayout_partial_name'
end
```

then in the main layout.html.erb (i.e. application.html.erb), where you would otherwise put your yield statement:

```
<%= @inner_layout ? render(:partial => "#{@inner_layout}") : yield %>
```

the assumtion is that the sublayout partial file will have its own yield statement in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

How about a much saner approach:

```
render :layout => false
```

Related: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: because I am rendering a layout.  AND an optional sub-layout.  Anyhow I solved the problem.  Will post it shortly.